# Can't load local CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

Trying to load standard CKEditor, when I load it from CDN:

```
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Everything works here. But when I try link to downloaded package:

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Here CKEditor loads in 'disabled' state - all buttons are disabled and no text inside.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to localization. CKEditor tries to load defult config based on server's environment.
Still don't know the cause. Temporary solved by setting config.language="en"